# Best practice to get Application Module for Online Web Service application

Tags: java, web-services, oracle11g, oracle-adf

I am building application using `Jdeveloper 11.1.1.7.0.` This application will run by a `scheduler` based on the time interval specified in the application. The main purpose of this application is to do online transaction using `Online Web Services`.

In the application I am fetching data form Database. In order to do that I have to define application Module and use it to get the `view objects`. Previously, developer used the following way for creating application module when the application was in `10g` (before migrate to `11g`):

```
ApplicationModule appMod= Configuration.createRootApplicationModule("somePackge","someAppNameLocal");
```

and at the end he release it as follow:

```
Configuration.releaseRootApplicationModule(appMod, false);
```

**Question is:** **What is the best practice to get the application module?**

This blog: [Oracle Apps (ADF/OAF/iModules): Different ways of getting Handle to AM from Backing Bean](http://ioracle-erp.blogspot.com/2012/08/different-ways-of-getting-handle-to-am.html) suggests different ways to do that. **But, Which one is the best for the type of application I am building? Also, Do I need some how to release the application module at the end of the application? Is it necessary?**

Comment: Getting an application module instance is like checking out a resource from AM pool. Releasing an application module instance resource is like checking it back in the application module pool so that it can be used by other users of application. Since number of instances available are limited, it will improve the scalability of your application and more users will be able to use it at any given time.

Answer (score 2):

The method you follow now **WOULD** be the best method.
I have been using the same in my application and it works fine in production.
I have the same use case as yours.

But you need to release your root application module using

```
Configuration.releaseRootApplicationModule(appMod, true);
```

not

```
Configuration.releaseRootApplicationModule(appMod, false);
```

Reason: http://www.jobinesh.com/2011/12/some-tips-on-application-module-usage.html

**Do I need some how to release the application module at the end of the application? Is it necessary?**

It IS NECESSARY.

Calling createRootApplicationModule() will use a connection from your connection pool and if you do not release it properly your application can crash at some point of time due to connection unavailability.

I would suggest following this post :http://andrejusb.blogspot.in/2013/03/optimizing-long-running-adf-operations.html
and create a AM for your scheduler.